# When a general goes to the graveyard in EDH, does his casting counter reset in the command zone?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

> 11) While a Commander is in the command zone, it may be cast. As an additional cost to cast a Commander from the command zone, its owner must pay {2} for each time it was previously cast from the command zone. (ie: it costs 6WW to cast for the third time.)

In a game last night someone tried to allow their commander to go to the graveyard as a method of resetting the casting penalty from the command zone.  While I agreed that the general could be brought back from the graveyard through normal means and cast without the penalty, I disagreed that allowing the general to go to the graveyard reset the counter in the command zone.

His argument was that it's in the graveyard, counters on a creature go away.  I argued the counter is not on the general at all, but rather is part of the state of the game/command zone.

Who was correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were correct in the assumption that the tracking of casting cost is not a counter, but a separate attribute of the game.

The [official EDH rules](http://www.dragonhighlander.net/rules.php) state:

> While a Commander is in the command zone, it may be cast. As an additional cost to cast a Commander from the command zone, its owner must pay {2} for each time it was previously cast from the command zone. (ie: it costs 6WW to cast for the third time.)

The Magic comprehensive rules state:

> 903.10. A player may cast a commander he or she owns from the command zone. Doing so costs that player an additional {2} for each previous time he or she cast that commander from the command zone that game.

Neither of these refer to "counters" at all - it's a static "every time you play this again, it costs {2} more."

Comment: It's important to note that being a commander is an attribute of the physical card (903.3). It is not related to the object that card represents (the creature/planewalker). An object changing zone becomes a new object (400.7) and usually looses all of it's previous attributes. But this doesn't apply to attributes of the *card*. The card is and remains the Commander no matter what zones it gets shuffled through. This is the same reason why copies of a commander do not deal commander damage. Those copies are not represented by a commander designated card.

Comment: ...and why a commander that becomes a copy of another creature (or morphs, or otherwise changes) still deals commander damage.